# Find Duplicate arrays and Intersection of arrays in array of hash values using Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I want to find duplicate Arrays from hash that contains arrays. Point is, I am trying to develop sets and storing them into hash table of Perl. After, I need to extract 
1. those arrays which are **completely** duplicate(Having all values same).
2. Intersection of arrays

```
Source code is given as under:  


use strict;
use warnings;

my @test1= ("Bob", "Flip", "David");
my @test2= ("Bob", "Kevin", "John", "Michel");
my @test3= ("Bob", "Flip", "David");
my @test4= ("Haidi", "Bob",  "Grook", "Franky");
my @test5= ();
my @test6=();

my %arrayHash= ( "ppl1" => [@test1],
             "ppl2"=> [@test2], 
             "ppl3" => [@test3],
             "ppl4"=> [@test4], 
             "ppl5"=> [@test5],
             "ppl6"=> [@test6],  

            );


Required Output:  ppl1 and   ppl3 have duplicate lists
Intersection of arrays= Bob
```

Kindly note that duplication of empty arrays is not desired!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check two arrays for equality for the hash keys.For that you can use [smart match operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator) for comparison.

Next you can use [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) to filter-out values which are not duplicates and a hash to keep track of values which are already checked.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @test1= ("Bob", "Flip", "David");
my @test2= ("Kevin", "John", "Michel");
my @test3= ("Bob", "Flip", "David");
my @test4= ("Haidi", "Grook", "Franky");
my @test5= ("Bob", "Flip", "David");
my @test6= ("Kevin", "John", "Michel");
my @test7= ("Haidi", "Grook", "Frank4");


my %arrayHash= ( "ppl1" => [@test1],
                 "ppl2"=> [@test2],
                 "ppl3" => [@test3],
                 "ppl4"=> [@test4],
                 "ppl5"=> [@test5],
                 "ppl6"=> [@test6],
                 "ppl7"=> [@test7]
                );

my %seen;
foreach my $key1 (sort keys %arrayHash){
   next unless @{$arrayHash{$key1}};
   my @keys;
   if(@keys=grep{(@{$arrayHash{$key1}} ~~ @{$arrayHash{$_}} ) && ($_ ne $key1) && (not exists $seen{$key1})}sort keys %arrayHash){
           unshift(@keys,$key1);
           print "@keys are duplicates \n";
           @seen{@keys}=@keys;
      }
}
```

**output:**

```
ppl1 ppl3 ppl5 are duplicates 
ppl2 ppl6 are duplicates
```

Comment: Is it possible avoid duplication detection for empty arrays. Trouble is, in my actual data, there are some cases of empty arrays as well. However, your code also detects their duplication as valid, which is not desired!

Comment: But they literally _are_ duplicates, by content.

Comment: @Sobrique indeed. @Analyzer you can just add condition to check if array is defined like `if(defined @{$arrayHash{$key1}}){...}`

Comment: Array in a scalar context returns number of elements. So `next unless @{$arrayHash{$key1}}` will probably do the trick too.

Comment: Thanks @Sobrique that is simpler approach.

Comment: Thanks. Shall respond after testing.

Comment: @Arunesh Smart match operator is used to match the strings enclosed in " ". How about using "eq" in the context of strings placed with " " as array elements?

Comment: @Analyzer could you be more specific . Sorry, I didn't get you?

Comment: @AruneshSingh Seems, it is working for me some how. Can you make little more contribution and write the code for finding intersection (Common elements ) among all the arrays of hash?

Comment: @Analyzer that is a different question. Please ask it separately.

Answer (score 1):

So there's a set of steps here:

- compare your arrays one to the other. This is harder because you're doing multi-element arrays. You can't directly test equivalence, because you need to compare *members*.
- Filter one from the other.

So first of all:

(Edit: Coping with empty)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @test1 = ( "Bob",   "Flip",  "David" );
my @test2 = ( "Kevin", "John",  "Michel" );
my @test3 = ( "Bob",   "Flip",  "David" );
my @test4 = ( "Haidi", "Grook", "Franky" );
my @test5 = ();
my @test6 = ();

my %arrayHash = (
    "ppl1" => [@test1],
    "ppl2" => [@test2],
    "ppl3" => [@test3],
    "ppl4" => [@test4],
    "ppl5" => [@test5],
    "ppl6" => [@test6],

);

my %seen;

#cycle through the hash
foreach my $key ( sort keys %arrayHash ) {

    #skip empty:
    next unless @{ $arrayHash{$key} };

    #turn your array into a string - ':' separated
    my $value_str = join( ":", sort @{ $arrayHash{$key} } );

    #check if that 'value string' has already been seen
    if ( $seen{$value_str} ) {
        print "$key is a duplicate of $seen{$value_str}\n";
    }
    $seen{$value_str} = $key;
}
```

Now note - this is a *bit* of a cheat - it sticks together your arrays with `:`, which doesn't work in every scenario.

`("Bob:", "Flip")` and `("Bob", ":Flip")` will end up the same.

It will also only print your most recent duplicate if you have multiple.

You can work around this - if you want - by pushing multiple values into the `%seen` hash.

Comment: Your code is quite understandable. However, it does not produce desired output. What it outputs is only those keys which are being duplicated. How can we edit the code to give out put keys which are duplicating with other keys. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @test1= ("Bob", "Flip", "David");
my @test2= ("Kevin", "John", "Michel");
my @test3= ("Bob", "Flip", "David");
my @test4= ("Haidi", "Grook", "Franky");

my %arrayHash= ( "1" => \@test1,
             "2"=> \@test2,
             "3" => \@test3,
             "4"=> \@test4,

            );

sub arrayCmp {
        my @array1 = @{$_[0]};
        my @array2 = @{$_[1]};

        return 0 if ($#array1 != $#array2);

        @array1 = sort(@array1);
        @array2 = sort(@array2);

        for (my $ii = 0; $ii <= $#array1; $ii++) {
                if ($array1[$ii] ne $array2[$ii]) {
                        #print "$array1[$ii] != $array2[$ii]\n";
                        return 0;
                }
        }

        return 1;
}


my @keyArr = sort(keys(%arrayHash));
for(my $i = 0; $i <= $#keyArr - 1; $i++) {

        my @arr1 = @{$arrayHash{$keyArr[$i]}};

        for(my $j = 1; $j <= $#keyArr; $j++) {
                my @arr2 = @{$arrayHash{$keyArr[$j]}};
                if ($keyArr[$i] ne $keyArr[$j] && arrayCmp(\@arr1, \@arr2) == 1) {
                        print "$keyArr[$i] and $keyArr[$j] are duplicates\n";
                }
        }
}
```

Outputs this

```
1 and 3 are duplicates
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But, still, it does not produce the desired output. I will be keen to get "1 and 3 are duplicates". More ever, I am using hash of arrays, so, processing should be carried out through hash

Comment: Add a simple check. When keys are equal, don't print "are duplicates" messages. Most of the hard work is done for you.

Comment: Edited answer. Enjoy!!

Comment: Thanks. Can we look for more easy approach :) ?

Comment: This is actually very simple approach. We are interating over hash map and comparing each element with every other element. Its just that perl syntax is making it difficult on eyes. Try to understand the code line by line to learn more about code. You have already saved a lot of time writing it, so spend it in understanding it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Sameer!  I am new to Perl Programming. Can you kindly have a look at my edited question. Shall your code work with edited one too?

Comment: Sameer! Can we avoid counting duplication for empty arrays in above code?

Comment: Sameer! I did it by putting check in compArray  subroutine. Can you update the code for finding intersection among the arrays, I am making update into the test code ?